# Making border of last item straight

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am working on angular app and I have  a progress bar and code is as follows :

```css
.bar {
  --d: 1rem;
  /* arrow depth */
  --gap: 0.3rem;
  /* arrow thickness, gap */
  display: flex;
  margin-right: var(--d);
}

.bar-step {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.6rem var(--d);
  margin-right: calc(var(--d) * -1 + var(--gap));
  background: #d9e3f7;
  color: #23468c;
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%, 0% 100%, var(--d) 50%);
}

.bar-step:first-child {
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.bar-step.active {
  background: #23468c;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="bar-step active">Step 1</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 2 text</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 3</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 4</div>
</div>
```

How I can make right border of last child same as left border of first child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting last element's clip path as below:

```css
.bar {
  --d: 1rem;
  /* arrow depth */
  --gap: 0.3rem;
  /* arrow thickness, gap */
  display: flex;
  margin-right: var(--d);
}

.bar-step {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.6rem var(--d);
  margin-right: calc(var(--d) * -1 + var(--gap));
  background: #d9e3f7;
  color: #23468c;
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%, 0% 100%, var(--d) 50%);
}

.bar-step:first-child {
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.bar-step:last-child {
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%, 0% 100%, var(--d) 50%)
}

.bar-step.active {
  background: #23468c;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="bar-step active">Step 1</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 2 text</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 3</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: apologies I left in a typo so it mucked it up, here's the new `clip-path` for the `last child`

```css
.bar {
  --d: 1rem;
  /* arrow depth */
  --gap: 0.3rem;
  /* arrow thickness, gap */
  display: flex;
  margin-right: var(--d);
}

.bar-step {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.6rem var(--d);
  margin-right: calc(var(--d) * -1 + var(--gap));
  background: #d9e3f7;
  color: #23468c;
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%, 0% 100%, var(--d) 50%);
}

.bar-step:first-child {
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.bar-step:last-child  {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, var(--d) 50%, 0% 0%);
}

.bar-step.active {
  background: #23468c;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="bar-step active">Step 1</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 2 text</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 3</div>
  <div class="bar-step">Step 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer disturbed shape of step from both ends. I want only right border. Spacing between step 3 and step 4 got distorted

Comment: sorry @Romio I left that in by mistake, but have corrected it now for the future